# Background-size issue in IE and Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am using background-size on Chrome and found out it is CSS3 which is not supported in old versions of IE. Hence I have gone through some posts and someone recommended to use this filter:

```
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader
```

HTML:

```html
<span class="num_blue_small small"><span class="numberText">4</span></span>
```

CSS:

```css
.num_blue_small
{
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
    src='/images/num_blue_small.png',
    sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/images/num_blue_small.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
 }

.small
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 35px;

}

.numberText
{
    color: White;
}
```

By implementing the "filter", it works perfectly in IE7; however, it turns invisible in Google Chrome.

If I include `background: url(/images/num_blue_ssc.png) no-repeat;` in `.num_blue_small` CSS class, it will work fine in Chrome but IE 7 will show 2 same images with different sizes.

What should I do to get it fixed?

Answer (score 1):

you could try the background-size polyfill

**[An IE behavior adding support for background-size to IE8.](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill)** of Louis Remi

> Progressive Enhancement is the mantra I live by. It means "Have fun
>   with CSS3 and don't worry about IE8 users; they'll never notice
>   they're missing out on your gorgeous text-shadows and gradients,
>   anyway".
>
> All was well until I discovered the elegance of background-size:
>   cover; and background-size: contain;. The first one, for instance,
>   allows an image to completely cover a background, without having to
>   send a 1920x1080 background image down the pipes.
>
> Unfortunately, they don't degrade gracefully: websites would likely
>   appear broken to IE8 users

They offer that feature:

- correct position and size of the background image
- updated position and size on browser resize
- updated image, position and size when the background-image is modified

but seems they have some limitation:

- multiple backgrounds (although the :after trick can still be used)
- 4 values syntax of background-position
- any repeat value in background-repeat
- non-default values of background-[clip/origin/attachment/scroll]
- resizing the background when the dimensions of the element change

Comment: is it suitable for mobile web page as well?

Comment: I'm sorry, I' don't know, but there is only polifill I know, and seem also the only suitable https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Comment: this is the native support of _backgroud-size_ http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts

Comment: ok. I will take a look later on. What I did for temporary is to resize the actual size of the image so i do not need to scale it in css / js